# How to compile bada gcc toolchain from command line?

Tags: c++, gcc, command-line, bada

I want to develop a helloworld application but want to compile it using Command line not by BADA IDE.

Comment: Your title is different from what you are asking. Are you trying to compile the toolchain or your own software written FOR bada?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile BADA application from Command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583236/compile-bada-application-from-command-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

First, compile it with bada IDE. Note the `g++` and `ld` commands in the console window (ignore the `make clean` phase). Then run the same from the command line. You'll probably have to modify PATH and/or other environment variables so that the toolchain can run, and so that the toolchain can find headers and libraries. All those live under `bada\(version)\Tools\Toolchains\ARM`.