# Compile BADA application from Command prompt

Tags: c++, command, prompt, bada

I want to develop a BADA application which will print the message Helloworld.I have downloaded BADA SDK.It could be done in BADA IDE but i want to compile and run it using command prompt.Now for that we need to compile it using GCC tool chain i think.My Helloworld code is in C:Helloworld.So i have changed directory to it and also have set path to C:\bada\1.0.0b3\Tools\Toolchains\Win32\bin where g++ is located.Now i am compiling it by using command  g++ -Wall Helloworld.cpp -o Helloworld.I am getting an error 
In file included from Helloworld.cpp:11:
HelloWorld.h:4: fatal error: FApp.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
FApp.h is already included in Helloworld.h. Still i am getting this error.When i am running the same code in BADA IDE its showing the output.Could any body help that what needs to be done to compile BADA application from command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler needs to know where to look for `#include` statements.  Your IDE will give it the `-Ic:\bada\1.0.0b3\...\includepath` BADA include folder, and that's what you will have to do on the command line.

Take a look at the [g++ documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/cpp/Search-Path.html#Search-Path).  The `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` [environment variable](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.0/cpp/Environment-Variables.html#Environment-Variables) may also be used (might be more convenient than setting the switch on every g++ command line.)

Note: your link path will probably need the same treatment.  It may be a good idea to look at the command line the IDE generates, and use that.

Comment: I have set the path for both INCLUDE and g++.
C:\Helloworld>g++ -Wall Helloworld.cpp -o Helloworld
In file included from Helloworld.cpp:1:
HelloWorld.h:4: fatal error: FBase.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
This is the error i am getting.

Comment: I am not getting how to do it either from g++ documentation not from environment variable.