# Compile BADA Sample ApplictaionApp from command prompt command

Tags: c++, command, prompt, bada

I am Compiling BADA sample appliction ApplicationApp but from command prompt.Now for thisi needed commands so i had a look at BADA IDE console while Building ApplicationApp.The command console showed for compiling was 
i686-mingw32-g++ -D_DEBUG -DSHP -DBUILD_DLL -I"C:/bada/1.0.0b3/include" -I"C:/bada/1.0.0b3/IDE/workspace2/AnimationApp/inc" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/AnimationApp.d" -MT"src/AnimationApp.d" -o"src/AnimationApp.o" "../src/AnimationApp.cpp"

which i converted to

g++ -I"C:/bada/1.0.0b3/include" -I"C:\bada\1.0.0b3\Samples\AnimationApp\inc" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -MMD -MP -MF"src/AnimationApp.d" -MT"src/AnimationApp.d" -o"src/AnimationApp.o" "C:\bada\1.0.0b3\Samples\AnimationApp\src\AnimationApp.cpp

Now i want to generate an .exe file using command prompt.the command which console showed for generating it was

'Building target: AnimationApp.exe'
'Invoking: bada C++ Linker'
i686-mingw32-g++ -L"C:/bada/1.0.0b3/Model/Wave_LP1/Simulator" -L"C:/bada/1.0.0b3/Lib" -L"C:/bada/1.0.0b3/IDE/workspace2/AnimationApp/lib" -shared -o"AnimationApp.exe"  /src/AnimationApp.o ./src/AnimationAppEntry.o ./src/Form1.o ./src/Form2.o ./src/Form3.o ./src/FormMgr.o   -losp_rt0 -lFMedia -lFApp -lFUi -lFUiControls -lFBase -lFSystem -lFGraphics
'Finished building target: AnimationApp.exe'

could anyone Help me that how to convert this command so that it could be run from command prompt.here Form1...FormMgr are various forms inside src/Applicationapp.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile BADA application from Command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583236/compile-bada-application-from-command-prompt)

Comment: Asking the same question again and again and again is not going to get you an answer. All it can get you is tons of bad reputation. Read the FAQ and improve your previous question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is fairly simple:

```
i686-mingw32-g++ -L"C:/bada/1.0.0b3/Model/Wave_LP1/Simulator" -L"C:/bada/1.0.0b3/Lib" -L"C:/bada/1.0.0b3/IDE/workspace2/AnimationApp/lib" -shared -o"AnimationApp.exe"  /src/AnimationApp.o ./src/AnimationAppEntry.o ./src/Form1.o ./src/Form2.o ./src/Form3.o ./src/FormMgr.o   -losp_rt0 -lFMedia -lFApp -lFUi -lFUiControls -lFBase -lFSystem -lFGraphics
```

Comment: The command prompt is showing input too long when i tried to execute the above command whereas C:/bada/1.0.0b3/IDE/workspace2/AnimationApp/lib is the workspace of the IDE.How to convert it from cmd..??

Comment: @Suvin sry, I don't know windows cmd line.  The best I can do, is possible recommend MinGW which has bash which in turn supports very long commands.